# modify a line using sed

Tags: sed

I need to used sed for following requirment using sed

I have one string as $str and I need to replace blow line in a file

```
abh{1..$abh}             cdf_$ghu,xyz                 *  abh{}.$xy
```

New modified line should be as below

```
abh{1..$abh}             cdf_$ghu,$str                 *  abh{}.$xy
```

Note `"xyz"` can be any arbitrary value. Could you please tell me how to do using sed in one liner.

```
sed 's/\(^\s*abh{1..$abh}\s*\)\(.*xyz\)/\1/' file.txt
```

but still does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `sed 's/xyz/$str/'`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's|\(\S\+\s\+[^,]\+,\)\S\+\(\s\+.*\)|\1$str\2|' file.txt 
abh{1..$abh}             cdf_$ghu,$str                 *  abh{}.$xy
```

Or even more simple:

```
$ sed 's|,\S\+|,$str|' example.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response It works but value from $str is not replaced rather $str is printed as literal. For example if $str="Hello" so "Hello" should be printed in modified line.

Comment: ok i need to put variable in single quote and it worked.                     sed 's|\(\S\+\s\+[^,]\+,\)\S\+\(\s\+.*\)|\1'$str'\2|' file.txt                                  Thanks all for your reponse

Comment: You also may change single quotes to double quotes, it enable variable's interpolation in string.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'abh{1..$abh}             cdf_$ghu,xyz                 *  abh{}.$xy' | sed 's/\(.*\$ghu,\)\(.*\)\( .*\)/\1\$str\3/g'
```

Comment: Select you code, and click the **`{}`** icon in the toolbar. It will indent your code.